# Numbers associated with boundaries of manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, gn.general-topology

I don't know what name if any is attached to the numbers I'm about to describe.

For a line segment, [a,b]
    the number is 1 if for any k in (a,b)
    and 2 if k=a or k=b.

For a square, [a,b] cross [c,d],
    the number is 1 if k is in the interior
    the number is 2 if k is on an edge
    the number is 4 if k is a corner

For a cube, [a,b] cross [c,d] cross [e,f],
    the number is 1 if k is in the interior
    the number is 2 if k is on an face
    the number is 4 if k is on an edge
    the number is 8 if k is a corner

The concept I'm interested in might change these numbers if the spaces are non-rectangular. So,

For a trapzoid,
    the number is 1 if k is in the interior
    the number is 2 for the edges
    at each corner number the number is inverse of the fraction of the angle of that corner compared to R^2.

Does this ring any bell for names that I can use for searching?

Comment: The think my question is related to the Lebesgue's density theorem. 

Comment: You're measuring solid angles.  Technically you're looking at the ratio of the solid angle (content) of the "link" of the stratum and the corresponding solid angle of a point in Euclidean space of the same dimension.  

Comment: I'm only measuring solid angles at the smallest non-empty boundary, not in general.

Comment: Well, you haven't said what it is you're doing.  The solid-angle interpretation is consisting with all your examples so perhaps provide an example that disagrees with this interpretation.  

Comment: How is it consistent with all my examples? Three out of the four examples aren't even in R^3 so solid angle doesn't even apply. In the lone R^3 example, solid angle only applies for the corners. 

Comment: "solid angle" can be interpreted in any dimension, in any Riemann manifold with corners. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calculating the approximate density of a set A (line segment, square, cube, etc) in a ε-neighbourhood of a point x. It's related to the Lebesgue's density theorem. (Actually I was calculating the inverse of these numbers.)

Comment: Right . . . hence Ryan's first comment above.
